# How to detect if an item in my ObservableCollection has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have a datagrid which is bound to `ObservableCollection<Product>`. When the grid is updated this automatically updates the Product object in my collection.

What I want to do now is to have some sort of even that is triggered when any object in the collection is updated -or- some sort of binding to the collection that will return true/false depedant on if any Product has been updated.

The overall objective is to have a save button on my main window that is disabled if no changes have been made to my collection and enabled if changes have been made.

I have read into `INotifyPropertyChange` but I dont see how I can use this to monitor changes on a whole collection.

Additionally, if I implement this interface on my Product class I dont see how my UI can monitor every product in the collection - or can it?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop

Comment: I'm using this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes

Answer (score 22):

- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Product` class with notification for every property.
- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your viewmodel.
- Add property `IsDirty` to your ViewModel (with notification through `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- In your viewmodel, subscribe to `CollectionChanged`

  ```
  public YourViewModel()
  {
      ...
      YourCollection.CollectionChanged += YourCollection_CollectionChanged; 
      ...
  }

  private void YourCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.OldItems != null)
          foreach(var oldItem in args.OldItems)
              oldItem.PropertyChanged -= YourItem_PropertyChanged;

      if (args.NewItems != null)
          foreach(var newItem in args.NewItems)
              newItem.PropertyChanged += YourItem_PropertyChanged;
  }

  private void Youritem_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
      IsDirty = true;
  }
  ```
- Now you can bind to `IsDirty` property of your viewmodel, for example, you can bind `Button.IsEnabled` property directly to it.

Comment: This ought to be set as the answer.

Comment: For this code to work, `foreach(var oldItem in args.OldItems)` should be changed to `foreach(Product oldItem in args.OldItems)` and `foreach(var newItem in args.NewItems)` to `foreach(Product newItem in args.NewItems)`. Also this answer should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

Just use the ObservableCollection.
It has an event called *CollectionChanged*. If you register it, you can do what you want. Example:

```
ObservableCollection<string> strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
strings.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(changed);
strings.Add("Hello");
strings[0] = "HelloHello";
```

And:

```
private void changed(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    //You get notified here two times.
}
```

Comment: Despite the MSDN documentation, CollectionChanged doesn't get invoked when objects in the collection change. Only when the collectoin itself has objects added or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The logic needs to go in your Model (Product class).
A clean approach would be to expose `IsDirty` property (backed by field) in your model.

And your ViewModel would have a Command binding with `CanSave` checking the internal collection, and return true if Any of the item in collection `IsDirty=true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event for each of the objects in your collection and firing this event, for example, in the setter of your objects can work.

However, I think you don't need to do all this to figure out if a cell is changed in your grid. I think you can do something like what they do here instead:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/81131225-90fb-40f9-a311-066952c7bc43