# Update datatable when changed data in the datagrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datatable

I'm new at WPF and for several days I can't find the answer to my question. Please, point me to the useful links...

I have a datatable that is bound to the datagrid.

```
public  class Customers:INotifyPropertyChanged
  private DataTable _contacts;
      public DataTable Contacts
      {
          get { return _contacts; }

          set
          {
              _contacts = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("Contacts"); 
          }
      }
       public Customers() 
      {
          RaisePropertyChanged("Contacts");
      }
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
          {
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }
      }
      public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
          if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
              this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          if(string.Compare(propertyName,"Contacts")==0)
          {
             var CustomerContacts = new CustomerContactsTable();
                                  if (Id != null)
                                      CustomerContacts.GetTableByCustomerId(Id);
                                  Contacts = CustomerContacts;
                                  //..here is logic for other properties..
          }         

      }
```

And here is xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}" TargetUpdated="dgContacts_TargetUpdated">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TelNo,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" />                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I don't know how is better to implement the updates of data into database. I want to get two lists of specified datarows: list with updated rows (within new rows inside) and list with deleted rows. I want to work with whole row, not with cells. And I don't use the DataTableAdapter. Any changes in datagrid don't provide the update of sourcecollection now.
What event it will be better to use (OnTargetUpdated,RowEditEnding etc.)? 
Don't beat me so much please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better bind a ObservableCollection instead of a DataTable into a Datagrid to notify inserts or deletes.

In the link below the solution I adopted to solve a similar problem, although additionally I also needed to update the values of the properties of my binded objects. Hope it helps...

[Datagrid Binding with specialized ObservableCollection that updates item changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211462/wpf-bound-datagrid-does-not-update-items-properties)

Oscar

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve modified or deleted rows from the dataset

```
var modifiedRows = Contacts.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
var deletedRows = Contacts.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
```

Consider, as an alternative approach, creating a new ContactViewModel class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Use this class as a representation of each row in the datatable.

Comment: thanks, `GetChanges` is returning nothing to me, bcoz when i modify data in the datagrid the source collection remains unchanged. I'll try to use special class for each row