# sum of filtered ICollectionView

Tags: wpf, filtering, observablecollection, icollectionview

suppose this base class

```
public class Contrat_Paye_Item 
    {
        public int     CPI_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string  CPI_TEXT { get; set; }
        public decimal CPI_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    }
```

in my view Model i have made a list from that class like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<Contrat_Paye_Item> listapayer;
public ObservableCollection<Contrat_Paye_Item> ListaPayer
{
    get
    {
        return listapayer;
    }
    set
    {
        listapayer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ListaPayer");
    }
}
```

and in the VM constructor, just some testdata :

```
 listapayer.Add(new Contrat_Paye_Item()
                    {
                        CPI_TYPE = 0,
                        CPI_TEXT = "Loyer",
                        CPI_AMOUNT = 100
                    });


listapayer.Add(new Contrat_Paye_Item()
                    {
                        CPI_TYPE = 1,
                        CPI_TEXT = "charge 1",
                        CPI_AMOUNT = 200
                    });

listapayer.Add(new Contrat_Paye_Item()
                    {
                        CPI_TYPE = 1,
                        CPI_TEXT = "Charges 2",
                        CPI_AMOUNT = 300
                    });
```

so the full list contain 3 item, **the total Amount is 600** .

in my viewmodel i have added a sublist with only items that their CPI_TYPE = 1 and bound it to a listbox without problem like this :

```
   public ICollectionView ListCharges
        {
            get
            {


                var sub= new CollectionViewSource { Source = listapayer }.View;
                sub.Filter = p => (p as Contrat_Paye_Item).CPI_TYPE == 1;
                return sub;
            }
        }
```

now what i want to display is  a list of my items , with a row that contain a **sum of amounts** items of the sublist . a bind it to a second listbox

something like :

loyer 100

charges 500

any idea, tip is welcome .
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding something like this before returning the sub:

```
        var d1 = (from a in sub.SourceCollection.OfType<Contrat_Paye_Item>() where a.CPI_TEXT == "Loyer" select a.CPI_AMOUNT).Sum();
        var d2 = (from a in sub.SourceCollection.OfType<Contrat_Paye_Item>() where a.CPI_TEXT.ToLower().StartsWith("charge") select a.CPI_AMOUNT).Sum();

        sub.AddNewItem(new Contrat_Paye_Item() { CPI_TEXT="Sum Loyer", CPI_AMOUNT = d1} );
        sub.CommitNew();
        sub.AddNewItem(new Contrat_Paye_Item() { CPI_TEXT = "Sum Charges", CPI_AMOUNT = d2 });
        sub.CommitNew();
```

//Edit

Note this as a more flexible possibility:

Do not use _CollectionViewSource _. Instead use the following as the *ItemsSource* of the *ListBox*:

```
     public ObservableCollection<Contrat_Paye_Item> ListCharges
    {
        get
        { 
            return new ObservableCollection<Contrat_Paye_Item>((from a in listapayer where a.CPI_TYPE == 1 select a));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks man, this would work in my scenario since i have just  a very small records so recreating the sum list is not a problem for me .
i am marking this as a solution for now , but :)

Comment: it would be nice if it was using the observable pattern,
i did not mention that for code clarity,  but actually i am using INotifyPropertyChanged Pattern both for classes and List.
the ObserableCollection is a modified One named NotifyPropertyChanged from this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes
wich allow notification on Items changes as well, so we can update summaries and things like that

Comment: so a solution that use INotifyPropertyChanged and CollectionChanged wouldbe much more usefull .
and hint on this would be great .
ps : is there a way to post formated long text and codes in the comments ? so wierd :p