# Set event on object's parameter updated in observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

As for question, I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects, declared in a `UserControl` and `binded` to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`.

Its properties are updated during the software run, eventually.

I would like to catch the update event.

I tried using the `CollectionChanged` event, but it isn't fired.

The collection is declared as belove:

```
    public ObservableCollection<BatchSensor> BatchSensors
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<BatchSensor>)GetValue(BatchSensorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BatchSensorsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BatchSensorsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BatchSensors), typeof(ObservableCollection<BatchSensor>), typeof(BL_BatchContainer), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

and initialized as follows

```
    public BL_BatchContainer(string title, ObservableCollection<BatchSensor> batchSensors)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = title;
        BatchSensors = new ObservableCollection<BatchSensor>();

        BatchSensors.CollectionChanged += OnListChanged;

        BatchSensors = batchSensors;
    }
```

The class `BatchSensor` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fires property change notifications.

```
public  class BatchSensor: ClassBase
{
    private bool? _error = null;
    public bool? Error { get => _error; set => SetAndNotifyIfChanged(ref _error, value); }
}
```

Comment: In case you are asking about updates of individual BatchSensor objects, the BatchSensor class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the relevant properties.

Comment: Updated the question to provide an answer to your answer :)

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you asking how to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event? Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8490533/1136211)?

Comment: Despite both the objects in the collection and the view are correctly updated, the event CollectionChanged for the collection never fires. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: That event would only be fired when elements are added to or removed from or replaced in the collection. That is not what happens when an element's properties change.

Comment: Yes. That's the whole point. So, back to the original question, is there any way to get an update when an object's property inside a collection gets updated?

Comment: Sure, subscribe to its PropertyChanged event, as shown in the answer to that other question.

Comment: The CollectionChanged is NEVER fired. Not even when I init the collection in the costructor. Should I try to add each single BatchSensor to the collection in a foreach loop?

Comment: The important point is that you attach a PropertyChanged handler to every item in the collection. If the collection is populated before you attach the CollectionChanged handler you would of course have to iterate over the already present items.

Comment: Another point, you are attaching the CollectionChanged event to a collection that is never used: `BatchSensors.CollectionChanged += OnListChanged;` followed by `BatchSensors = batchSensors;` is wrong. Revert the order of the statements. Do not even assign `new ObservableCollection<BatchSensor>();`.