# Textbox in listbox not updating when lostfocus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, inotifypropertychanged

I have a textbox inside of a listbox that I would like to update the ObservableCollection when the textbox loses focus.  I tried using my collections CollectionChanged event as described in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706754/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-on-ischecked-isnt-firing-on-itemssource-of/5708274#5708274) to try to solve the problem.  Right now the only way to update the collection is if I add or remove an item from the listbox. Am I going about this the wrong way?  What am I missing for the textbox to update the collection?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataLogList,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding DataLogLabel}" Margin="5"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding DataLogName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Margin="5" Width="150"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public MainViewModel()
    { 
        DataLogList = new ObservableCollection<DataLogContent>();
        DataLogList.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {                
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (DataLogContent item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (DataLogContent item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
```

DataLogContent.cs

```
public class DataLogContent:ViewModelBase
{
    private string dataLogLabel;
    public string DataLogLabel
    { 
        get { return this.dataLogLabel; }
        set
        {
            this.dataLogLabel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string dataLogName;
    public string DataLogName
    {
        get { return this.dataLogName; }
        set
        {
            this.dataLogLabel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working based on this. My guess is that you may be over complicating the adding/removing logic of an item inside the `ObservableCollection`. There's no need to monitor the property changed event, as each object will already raise the event whenever a property within it changes.

Here's what I have:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataLogContent> DataLogList { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DataLogList = new ObservableCollection<DataLogContent>();
            DataLogList.Add(new DataLogContent
            {
                DataLogLabel = "Label",
                DataLogName = "Name"
            });

            DataLogList.Add(new DataLogContent
            {
                DataLogLabel = "Label2",
                DataLogName = "Name2"
            });
        }
    }

    public class DataLogContent : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string dataLogLabel;
        public string DataLogLabel
        { 
            get { return this.dataLogLabel; }
            set
            {
                this.dataLogLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataLogLabel");
            }
        }

        private string dataLogName;
        public string DataLogName
        {
            get { return this.dataLogName; }
            set
            {
                this.dataLogName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataLogName");
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Simple ViewModelBase:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataLogList,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding DataLogLabel}" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DataLogName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Margin="5" Width="150"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: I noticed that right after I posted.  I changed but did't fix the problem.

Comment: @mrsargent, I'll take a look again

Comment: Thanks. I added a label to the window to confirm they are changing (<label content={Binding DataLogList[0].DataLogName}/>) and indeed it is.  I guess what I was trying to do was when the DataLogList was modified to execute some additional logic.  I thought I could put this additional logic in the setter of the DataLogList property so when the collection is changed it would run the code. But that isn't working as I expected.  How could I run additional code when the textbox loses focus?

Comment: Since the binding "sets" when DataLogName loses focus, you can put that logic inside its setter. OR, you can create a custom event that fires inside the setter of DataLogName and listen to that inside the MainViewModel

Comment: That is my problem that I am having trouble understanding.  When the textbox loses focus it seems to not be hitting the setter of the DataLogList property.  I can put a breakpoint on it and it never hits it.                                 private ObservableCollection<DataLogContent> dataLogList;
        public ObservableCollection<DataLogContent> DataLogList
        {
            get { return this.dataLogList; }
            set
            {               
                    this.dataLogList = value;
                   
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Re-read what I put. It hits the setter of DataLogName when it loses focus, NOT the DataLogList. The binding of lose focus is used for DataLogName, as specified in the XAML.